# Get all related many-to-many from all records instead from each record laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, join, eloquent

I have `posts` table related with `tags` table via `post_tags`. I want to get all tags from all user post. let's say a user have 3 posts, then I want to get all tags from 3 of them without loop in user post to get individual related tags of each post, it's like join + distinct but maybe there is method in Eloquent to make it easy. Thanks, let me know if my question is unclear or duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$tags = Tag::whereHas('posts', function($q) use($userId) {
    $q->where('user_id', $userId);
})->get();
```

Comment: `user_id` not found, because posts table is never called in query builder, so there is no user_id column.

Comment: @AnggaAriWijaya if you don't have `user_id` in the `posts` table, this means you didn't define Eloquent relationships properly.

Comment: I have, but your code it directing up it's return one record only.

Comment: @AnggaAriWijaya if you want to get all tags which a user using in his posts, then this code is 100% working. If that's not what you need, please explain what do you want to get.

Comment: I get it, I'm sorry before, I have mistype in my relationship reverse in tag model so it never reach the post at the first place. I'll accept your answer, thanks.